# AppleScript - determine the network service to which the current IP address is bound

Tags: macos, applescript, network-service, system-preferences, systemevent

The following AppleScript code will return all the network services in the Network Setup.

```
tell application "System Events"
        tell current location of network preferences
            set names to get name of every service
        end tell
 end tell
```

How do I get only the active network service name instead of all?

Update with *clarification*: 'active' in this context means the network service to whose interface the current [primary] IPv4 address is bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@mcgrailm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24481701/45375) shows you how to obtain *all active* (read: *not disabled*) network services, *whether currently bound to addresses or not*.

This answer, by contrast, shows you how to **determine the network service to whose interface the current (primary) IPv4 address is bound**:

Unfortunately, this is non-trivial, as the information must be drawn from several sources:

- The `services` objects (from dictionary `System Events.sdef`) contains no information about currently bound addresses.
- However, a `service` object's `interface` property contains a `MAC address` property.
- While `IPv4 address of (system info)` returns the current (primary) IPv4 address, sadly, `primary Ethernet address of (system info)` always returns the *wired* Ethernet interface's MAC address, which may or may not be the interface to which the current IPv4 address is bound.
- Thus, to determine the MAC address corresponding to the current IPv4 address, the solution below uses `do shell script` to parse the output from CLI `ifconfig` with help from `awk`.

```applescript
# Obtain the [network] `service` instance underlying the 
# current IPv4 address...
set serviceWithPrimaryIpv4Address to my networkServiceByIp4Address("")
# ... and extract the name.
set nameOfServiceWithPrimaryIpv4Address to name of serviceWithPrimaryIpv4Address

# ---- Helper handlers.

# SYNOPSIS
#   networkServiceByIp4Address([addr])
# DESCRIPTION
#   Given (one of) the local system's IPv4 address(es), returns the network service object whose interface
#   the address is bound to (class `network service` is defined in `Sytem Events.sdef`).
#   If `addr` is an empty string or a missing value, the current primary IPv4 address is used.
#  An error is thrown if no matching service is found.
on networkServiceByIp4Address(addr)
  local macAddress
  set macAddress to my ip4ToMacAddress(addr)
  tell application "System Events"
    try
      tell current location of network preferences
        return first service whose (MAC address of interface of it) is macAddress
      end tell
    end try
  end tell
  error "No network service found matching IP address '" & addr & "'." number 500
end networkServiceByIp4Address

# SYNOPSIS
#   ip4ToMacAddress([addr])
# DESCRIPTION
#   Given (one of) the local system's IPv4 address(es), returns the corresponding network interface's
#   MAC address (regardless of interface type).
#   If `addr` is an empty string or a missing value, the current primary IPv4 address is used.
#  An error is thrown if no matching MAC address is found.
on ip4ToMacAddress(addr)
  if addr as string is "" then set addr to IPv4 address of (system info)
  try
    do shell script "ifconfig | awk -v ip4=" & ¬
      quoted form of addr & ¬
      " 'NF==2 && $2 ~ /^[a-f0-9]{2}(:[a-f0-9]{2}){5}$/ {macAddr=$2; next} $1 == \"inet\" && $2 == ip4 {print macAddr; exit}'"
    if result ≠ "" then return result
  end try
  error "No MAC address found matching IP address '" & addr & "'." number 500
end ip4ToMacAddress

my ip4ToMacAddress("")
```

Comment: good catch @mklement0, I should have know that's what the OP meant. This is a great answer and very detailed thank you !

Comment: @CodenameK: You're welcome; I'm glad to hear it. For the benefit of future readers: Would you mind updating the question and its title to clarify what you mean by 'active'?

Comment: Hello, you code helped a lot. Now it is not detecting the connection from 4G sticks. Do you know what changes needs to be made in the code to get it?

Comment: @CodenameK: I've just updated the `ip4ToMacAddress()` handler to look for ANY type of interface (not just `ether`, as before), which hopefully makes it detect the 4G connection, too.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to include it in your query :)

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell current location of network preferences
        set names to get name of every service whose active is true
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks. However this showed all the Network Service names instead of just the active one.

Comment: it does give the list of "active" services just not bound to IPV4 lol if you click on a service then click the gear at the bottom you can set the service to inactive if it's active and vise versa, that's what i thought you were referring to

Comment: Thanks this was helpful too. This can be used when I need to get all the Network services to a list.